# Php code that outputs as an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to create a php script that outputs json in the following format but I don't seem to be getting around it.

```
{
  "authentication_credentials": {
    "api_key": "hybghhmimjij48fr847gt4fdf847v8",
    "app_secret": "84984ff48448gf484198dfs818"
  },
  "sms_payload": [
    {
      "message": "Test Message",
      "msisdn": "123456789",
      "third_party_message_id": "samplestring"
    }
  ],
  "sender_id": "12345"
}
```

Here is the php code that I am trying to convert json

```
$api_key = "hybghhmimjij48fr847gt4fdf847v8";
$app_secret = "84984ff48448gf484198dfs818";
$message = "Test Message";
$msisdn = '123456789';
$third_party_message_id = 'samplestring';
$sender_id = '12345';


$data .= array('api_key'=>$api_key,'app_secret'=>$app_secret);
$data .= array('message'=>$message,'msisdn'=>$msisdn,'third_party_message_id'=>$third_party_message_id);
$data .= array('sender_id'=>$sender_id);


$data_string = json_encode($data);
echo  $data_string;
```

What other twerks should I add to the code to make it output json in the above format.

Comment: have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encode as like that:

```
$data['authentication_credentials'] = array('api_key'=>$api_key,'app_secret'=>$app_secret);

$data['sms_payload'] = array('message'=>$message,'msisdn'=>$msisdn,'third_party_message_id'=>$third_party_message_id); 

$data['sender_id'] = $sender_id;

echo json_encode($data);
```

**Some Explanation**:

As per your required json result you need to use `associative array` not concatenated variables.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

After checking your last comments:

***that is technically what i wanted to achieve. 
Thanks it solve my problem. – nick 7 hours ago***

I am adding this solution as a UPDATE 1 for future visitors:

```
$data['sms_payload'] = array(
                        array(
                        'message'=>$message,
                        'msisdn'=>$msisdn,
                        'third_party_message_id'=>$third_party_message_id
                    ));
```

**Result:**

```
"sms_payload":[{"message":"test","msisdn":"111","third_party_message_id":13213}]
```

Comment: as per my json output requirement, is it not supposed to be a non-associative array output as object

Comment: yes...a small issue come up though..the square brackets are missing in the output

Comment: @nick I don't think its needed but u can test like: array(array('message'=>$message,'msisdn'=>$msisdn,'third_party_message_id'=>$third_party_message_id));

Comment: that is technically what i wanted to achieve. Thanks it solve my problem.

Comment: @nick that's good don't forget to appreciate and also accept the answer it will help to others

Answer (score 0):

Use option `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`

```
$data_string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo  $data_string;
```

[More](http://php.net/json_encode) about this command

**EDIT**

And how I see, you have problems with data prepare, you must write something like this:

```
$data = (object)[
    "authentication_credentials" =>
        (object)[
        'api_key' => $api_key,
        'app_secret' => $app_secret
    ],
    //...
];
```